# Alfresco extension class files

Tags: alfresco

As part of customizing Alfresco, I have created a java class by extending 'org.quartz.StatefulJob'Action class in Alfresco. I have registered in Spring Bean definition. But I am getting error as follows. I am deploying this Tomcat server

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld] for bean with name 'helloWorld' defined in file [C:\alfresco-content-services\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\move-monthily-data-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1270)
```

Can i know the reason of this error ? , What exatctly is the right locaiton to keep extended java file in tomcat?  I am using Alfresco 5.2 EE ,

Rergards

Comment: Could you provide more details about your java file? As I understand you didn't package to amp or jar and just put it to tomcat?

Comment: I have packaged this class in a jar file and copied into  folder - tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\lib directory .  spring xml in following folder -tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension. I wasnt creating AMP  ,  copying it manually.

Comment: It says it can find the class "com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld" that is registered of the "helloworld" bean in "move-monthily-data-context.xml"
If you are not using amp or jar, would like to place the class files directly in location, you need to place the respective .class file under "webapps/alfresco/classes/com/tutorialspoint/HelloWorld" of your repo folder

Answer (score 1):

You should be creating a project based on the SDK and packaging your customizations as an AMP which you then install into your Alfresco and/or Share WAR files.

If you need help stepping through how to do that, please work through the [tutorials on ECM Architect](https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series).

Doing so will package your action class into a JAR and will then place your JAR in the Alfresco WAR under WEB-INF/lib.